How to build OpenSSL from source, without depending on /lib/libcrypto.so
After several sessions with intense Google searching and trying several angles with ChatGPT, I seem to be at a dead-end, my problem arises when I try to build OpenSSL from source, it seems that the build process wants to link with libcrypto.so located in /lib, but the system supplied version of OpenSSL is ancient, so this fails miserably, since OpenSSL now includes functionality not present in my version of libcrypto.so, specifically QUIC, its failing on safe_muldiv_uint64_t. It seems like a catch-22, and I have absolutely no idea how to break out of this.
Some of the suggestions I have found involved building OpenSSL in a chroot jail, but I think it seems a little excessive?
So I guess my question is: How do I build OpenSSL without linking with /lib/libcrypto.so, but linking with the version of libcrypto from the source package?
Output:
${LDCMD:-cc} -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -O2 -O3 -pipe -I/usr/include -I/usr/pkg/include  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/pkg/gcc7/lib/gcc/x86_64--netbsd/7.5.0 -Wl,-R/usr/pkg/gcc7/lib/gcc/x86_64--netbsd/7.5.0 -Wl,-zrelro -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/pkg/lib -Wl,-R/usr/pkg/lib \
        -o fuzz/quic-srtm-test \
        fuzz/quic-srtm-test-bin-fuzz_rand.o \
        fuzz/quic-srtm-test-bin-quic-srtm.o \
        fuzz/quic-srtm-test-bin-test-corpus.o \
        libssl.a libcrypto.a -pthread
...
apps/libapps.a -lssl -lcrypto -pthread
./libssl.so: undefined reference to safe_muldiv_uint64_t
./libssl.so: undefined reference to safe_mul_uint64_t

-L/usr/lib is specified in the above command executed by the Makefile, and that folder contains libcrypto.o and libssl.o from the system supplied version of OpenSSL,

I have been smashing this for two weeks now, I have lost track of what I have tried, but a quick summary: building static, passing arguments to make to point to the source supplied lib and include folders, trying a gazillion different settings in mk.conf, I have read this: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation and I have been following all the suggestions from there, still, no luck.

apps/libapps.a -lssl -lcrypto -pthread
./libssl.so: undefined reference to safe_muldiv_uint64_t
./libssl.so: undefined reference to safe_mul_uint64_t

No, I won't add safe_math.h to PLIST, it makes no sense when safe_math.h is internal, and not meant to end up in my include directory

Could this be caused by the order of library paths? if for some reason /usr/lib is searched before openssl/lib ? could this not result in libapps.a being linked against the system version of OpenSSL instead of libcrypto and libssl from the source package?

It could, but the build sets things up so that the newly-built libraries should be preferred — when it links you should see -L. in the arguments to the compiler, and libcrypto.so and libssl.so in the current directory.

Have you read all the files in your source directory with uppercase names? This sounds like it"s fixable with the configure script.

I have read all documentation files, and a lot of documentation on the OpenSSL site, I can't see how I am supposed to fix this with the configure script? I am already using --prefix and --openssldir, I can't see how --lib is going to help, as that seems to only be relevant when the build is finished, unless i read the documentation wrong?

You read the documentation wrong.

From INSTALL.md: The name of the directory under the top of the installation directory tree (see the --prefix option) where libraries will be installed. By default this is lib. Note that on Windows ... Some build targets have a multilib postfix set in the build configuration. For these targets the default libdir is lib. Please use --libdir=lib to override the libdir if adding the postfix is undesirable. If I am supposed to fix this with --libdir, "where libraries will be installed." Then the documentation is extremely poorley written
